# javascript escolher perguntas aleatórias

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar um projeto e resolvi que fará 5 perguntas, todas de sim ou não, ai eu quero que as perguntas sejam escolhidas aleatoriamente, tentei usar o math.random e algumas perguntas n funcionam direito, alguem pode me ajudar? segue o problema(fiz ele separado do projeto so para tentar corrigir o erro e depois implementar a historia):

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
let pontos = 0
let randomNumber;
let tmp;
const maxNumbers = 10;
let list = [];

//perguntas

const a = "a"
const b = "b"
const c = "c"
const d = "d"
const e = "e"
const f = "f"
const g = "g"
const h = "h"
const i = "i"
const j = "j"

//gerar lista:

for (let i = 0; i < maxNumbers; i++) {
    list[i] = i + 1;
 }
 
for (let i = list.length; i;) {
    randomNumber = Math.random() * i-- | 0;
    tmp = list[randomNumber];
    // troca o número aleatório pelo atual
    list[randomNumber] = list[i];
    // troca o atual pelo aleatório
    list[i] = tmp;
}


//função para aleatoridade:

function oi(id){
    let pergunta
    if(list[id] == 1){
        pergunta = a
    }else if(list[id] == 2){
        pertunga = b
    }else if(list[id] == 3){
        pergunta = c
    }else if(list[id] == 4){
        pergunta = d
    }else if(list[id] == 5){
        pergunta = e
    }else if(list[id] == 6){
        pergunta = f
    }else if(list[id] == 7){
        pergunta = g
    }else if(list[id] == 8){
        pergunta = h
    }else if(list[id] == 9){
        pergunta = i
    }else if(list[id] == 0){
        pergunta = j
    }
    return pergunta;

}
console.log(list)
console.log(oi(1))
console.log(oi(2))
console.log(oi(3))
console.log(oi(4))
console.log(oi(5))
console.log(oi(6))
console.log(oi(7))
console.log(oi(8))
console.log(oi(9))
console.log(oi(0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para facilitar tanto a escrita do seu código, como a solução do mesmo, recomendo primeiramente que suas perguntas sejam inseridas em um Array, podendo ser feito dessa forma:

```
let perguntas = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
```

Após isso basta utilizar o Math.random(), determinando seu limite como a quantidade de elementos do seu Array (length), e com isso acessando um índice de seu Array a partir do número que foi gerado aleatoriamente, deixando o código final dessa forma:

```js
let perguntas = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

let nmrRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * perguntas.length);

console.log(perguntas[nmrRandom]);
```

Comment: muito obrigado por responder Gustavo, eu estava deixando cada vez maior o código por bobeira minha kkkkk, tu me trouxe a luz, obrigado viu!